# fetch api requests in a specific order

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to fetch some information, using JavaScript fetch. Like this:

```
function apiReq (ids){
var api = ("https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/" + ids);
fetch(api)

.then (result => result.json())
.then ((res) => { 
    
    (res)
    
    var charInfo = document.getElementById("banner");
   
    var label = document.querySelector(".characters__container");
    var cardBody = document.querySelector(".card-body");
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    label.appendChild(ul);
    charInfo.appendChild(label);

    switch (ids) {

            case ids:   cardBody.innerHTML += "<h3 class='card-title'>" + res.name + "</h3>";
                        cardBody.innerHTML += "<p class='card-text'> Title: <br>" + res.titles[0] + "</p>";
                        
                        if(res.titles[0] == "") {
                
                        cardBody.innerHTML += "<p class='card-text'>Unknown</p>";
                            
                        }
            
                        cardBody.innerHTML += "<p class='card-text'>Alias: <br>" + res.aliases[0] + "</p>";
                        cardBody.innerHTML += "<p class='card-text'> Born: <br>" + res.born + "</p>";
                break;
    }
    
})
    
.catch (error => console.log(error))
    
};

apiReq(148);    // Arya Stark
apiReq(583);    // Jon Snow
apiReq(957);    // Sansa Stark
apiReq(338);    // Eddard Stark
apiReq(529);    // Jamie Lannister
apiReq(1052);   // Tyrion Lannister
apiReq(565);    // Joffrey Baratheon
apiReq(901);    // Robert Baratheon
apiReq(1022);   // Theon Greyjoy
apiReq(1303);   // Daenerys Targaryen
```

What I want is to make the *ids* appear in order, so that it always fetches Arya Stark first, then Jon Snow and so on... How can I make that happened? Or is it a way to make the fetch always fetch in a particular order (maybe using sort or something)?

It is important to fetch them in a specific order, so that it match up with the different images I have gotten for this project.

Comment: `switch (ids) { case ids: ... }`? o.O

Comment: Add the id (`data-character-id="148"`) to the image and it is irrelevant in which order you grab the info

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I tried that bow, but it sadly did not work. The images does not match up with the name

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the function async and await for each request to make them in order

```js
async function apiReq (ids){
// your code
}

await apiReq(148);    // Arya Stark
await apiReq(583);    // Jon Snow
await apiReq(957);    // Sansa Stark
await apiReq(338);    // Eddard Stark
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly this did not work (if I did it correctly). They still shows up randomly after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee the fetch order, you need to use the `async/await` syntax :

```
const charInfo = document.getElementById("banner");
const label = document.querySelector(".characters__container");

const apiReq = async (id) => {

    const api = ("https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/" + id);

    try {
        const response = fetch(api);
        const res = await response.json();

        var cardBody = document.querySelector(".card-body");
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");

        label.appendChild(ul);
        charInfo.appendChild(label);

        cardBody.innerHTML += .....

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

};

( async() => {
    await apiReq(148);    // Arya Stark
    await apiReq(583);    // Jon Snow
    await apiReq(957);    // Sansa Stark
    await apiReq(338);    // Eddard Stark
    await apiReq(529);    // Jamie Lannister
})()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly this did not work. I only got an error message, saying that response.json is not a function